# Why onKeyDown is triggered after onBlur when Tab pressed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I have strange problem. I want to make page accessible, keyboard friendly. I want to switch between items via Tab button and press it by Space or Enter. But when I added onKeyDown event for Material UI button, the callback is not run when button pressed but after I switch to another element. For me it looks like a bug.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-tdd-xyjt8y

```
 <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
  <Button variant="text" onKeyDown={() => { console.log("fooo") }}>Text</Button> 
  <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button> // foo is displayed when focus jumps to this element
  <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
</Stack>
```

Comment: I changed onKeyDown to onClick and it worked. The onClick handler works for mouse clicks and keyboard interactions like space and enter like how you want. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: HTML buttons works like that by default, you don't need a special handling for keyboard

Comment: Pressing tab is also registered as `keydown` hence your code runs

Answer (score 1):

> the callback is not run when button pressed but after I switch to another element

I'm not seeing that behavior with your example. I even added an onBlur() and onFocus() handler to your example.

```
<Button variant="text" onKeyDown={() => { console.log("keydown") }} onFocus={() => { console.log("focus") }} onBlur={() => { console.log("blur") }}>Text</Button>
```

When I <kbd>tab</kbd> **to** the "Text" button, I see "focus" in the console.

When I <kbd>tab</kbd> **off** the "Text" button, I see "keydown" in the console followed by "blur".

The "keydown" event is triggered because I pressed a keyboard key (the <kbd>tab</kbd> key). The "blur" event is triggered because the "Text" button lost focus (because I pressed <kbd>tab</kbd>).

Comment: But keydown should be triggered very first. Before all other

Comment: Why and what doc says that?  The order of events that I posted is exactly the right order.  Maybe you need to post the events that you are seeing in order and then what do you think that order should be.

Comment: how is that possible that key down (which obviously should be first than key up - that how keyboards are build - you pressing buttons, not pulling them up) is triggered after keyup on the same element?

Comment: You have said nothing about a keyup event in your question. Like I said, maybe update your question to ask specifically about what events you're asking about and what order you think they should be.  Your question currently asks about a blur event.